# How to implement 360 video and Sound in Unity3D for VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-editing, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality

Can someone please provide me some insights about how the pipeline is to implement 360 video and sound in VR? I know a thing or two about video editing, sound and unity3d but would like to know more about how to do all these things for VR. Lets say I want to shoot a 360 video, then put it on VR but also I want to incorporate the sound captured. Also I would like to have some interactive spots on it.

Edit: If I want to make interactive spots on it, will that mean I need different 360 cameras shooting from the spots I want the interaction to happen? or will the one video shot with one camera allowed for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First you have to choose target platfrom e.g. IOS,Android etc. Than you have to find out video player which support 360 video like AVPROMEDIAPLAYER from unitiy3d's AssetStore.
for Interactive spots in video you have to make some local database like thing e.g. xml file for position of trigger and time for doing any activity.Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks user5891718. So lets say I decided to go with Android and found the video player. Will I just import the edited video and sound separately to Unity and from there do the other work?